# Cutting the points evenly

Tags: mathematics, geometry

I draw an even number of points on a piece of paper. Is it possible to cut the paper into two pieces with a single straight cut, such that:

1. Each piece gets the same number of points
2. The cut does not go through any points

Comment: Weird that there were four answers to this question, nearly an hour after it was posted yet within sixty seconds of each other.

Comment: There is a more interesting version in which you have two kinds of points, say red and blue ones, and have to split both colours in half simultaneously. This is a [discrete version of the Ham Sandwich Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_sandwich_theorem#Discrete_and_computational_geometry_versions). I think you then need to impose the constraint that no three points lie in a straight line, or else have rules about allowing your cut to go through one or more points.

Comment: Here too, some of the drawn points may have to be unique to have such a cut...

Comment: I found a similar question on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106324/dividing-a-plane-of-points-into-two-equal-halves

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

> yes, obviously.

Because

> If you rotate the paper, there are only a finite number of angles where two points overlap on the X axis.  There are plenty of ways to rotate the paper in a way that no two points share the same X coordinate.
>
>  Chose such a rotation and cut the paper vertically between the two middle points.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming no two points occupy the same place

> it is always possible. There are only finitely many pairs of points, and thus finitely many *exceptional* slopes where some lines with that slope pass through more than one point.
>
>  So pick one of the (continuum-many) non-exceptional slopes and draw a line $l$ with the chosen slope not meeting any point. Beside each point write its signed distance to $l$; by non-exceptionality of the slope and our prior asssumption the distances will be distinct and will sort the points. A line $l'$ with the desired property is then any line parallel to $l$ where the two points with **median** distance are on opposite sides of $l'$.

This assumption is necessary:

> Suppose there are just two points but they occupy the same spot. Then obviously no line satisfies the given constraints.

Comment: You beat me for 11 seconds!  Same idea.

Comment: don't you want l' to be perpendicular to l?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Please rrad my answer carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Only if

> Just kidding! You can always do this. (Assuming you don't draw two points in the same location, which strikes me as *unchivalrous behavior*.)

> First, sort the points by increasing x coordinate, with ties broken by increasing y coordinate, and draw a vertical line just to the right of point `n/2`. If this works, cut along that line, obviously. It won't work if `x(n/2)` happens to be equal to `x(n/2-1)` and/or `x(n/2+1)`.

> Otherwise, first move the line directly onto point `n/2`. Then pick a location between point `n/2` and point `n/2+1`, then infinitesimally rotate the line counterclockwise about that location. Cut along that line. The result will have points `1` through `n/2` on the left, and points `n/2+1` through `n` on the right.

Note that

> This is the same approach as Florian's and Parcly's, but involves a uniquely determined slope. (Which is great for proofs, but I wouldn't do it this way in real life.)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible.

> For simplicity, we use the possibility that your even number was a 2 (because your puzzle simply asks if it's possible to do so after you have chosen an even number).
>  
>  Follow these steps:
>  
>  1. Choose 2 as your even number. 
>  2. Draw two dots on a piece of paper. 
> 3. Cut the paper in two such that there is a dot on both pieces.